# Get the first 5 elements of a Map in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I'm making a Java project for the university. I need to add in a String list the first 5 values of a Map, but I can't seem to find a way to iterate over just 5 elements and not all the elements like using an Iterator

Basically I have a Map declared as follows: `Map<String, Integer> infl_numbers = new HashMap<>();`

I want to do something like this:

```
for (short i =0;i<5;i++){
    // element = get i-th element of the Map
    // list.add(element)
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `HashMap` isn't ordered - the sort order of the elements is explicitly not defined. So you'll likely get different elements on every run of your application.

Comment: Define what `first` means, Map's keys are backed by `Set` which by contract does not have defined order.

Comment: There are other types of Map that do provide ordering, though - have a look at `LinkedHashMap` which can provide insertion order or access order, depending on configuration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I efficiently iterate over each entry in a Java Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-java-map)

Comment: Since you don't care about keys, you can directly iterate over values `infl_numbers.values().stream().limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashMap` is the wrong class for this requirement. Since the elements in a `HashMap` are not ordered, you may get a different set of five elements each time. You should use `LinkedHashMap` which maintains the insertion order. Then, you can iterate the key set and get the first five elements with the help of a counter e.g.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("One", 1);
        map.put("Two", 2);
        map.put("Three", 3);
        map.put("Four", 4);
        map.put("Five", 5);
        map.put("Six", 6);
        map.put("Seven", 7);
        map.put("Eight", 8);
        map.put("Nine", 9);
        map.put("Ten", 10);

        // Access first five elements
        int count = 0;
        Iterator<String> itr = map.keySet().iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext() && count < 5) {
            System.out.println(map.get(itr.next()));
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Good explaination, but a minor detail is missing: OP asked for a `Map<String, Integer>`, you provided the opposite generic types `Map<Integer, String>`.

Comment: Thanks, @Glains for the support and for pointing it out. I've updated the `Map` to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything with an index (i = 0..4) directly on a Map because maps are generally unordered.  Same with Sets.  So all you can do is start processing a map, getting whatever items you get, and then stop after you've gotten 5 items:

```
int count = 0;
for (String key : infl_numbers.keySet()) {
    list.add(infl_numbers.get(key))
    count++;
    if (count == 5)
        break;
}
```

There are some types of Maps that are ordered.  So if you have a reference to one of those rather than just a reference to a Map, the story is different, and depends on the subtype of Map you're dealing with.